# Is it possible to get cells to display the hour format in decimal form in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets

Currently, I have the time duration in the form hh:mm:ss. However, I would like it to be converted to hours (in decimal format) such that a duration of 02:30:00 is converted to 2.5 (hours) within the cell. I can only find an 'hour' option within Google Spreadsheet, which only seems to show whole numbers for hours (such that 02:30:00 is just converted to 2(hours)).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function to read the format from one cell and modify it in another.

In cell A5 I have placed time format of 02:30

In cell B5 I have placed the following =(hour(A5)+minute(A5)/60)

This gives 2.5 by returning the hour as 2 and adding minutes(30)/60 as 0.5